# Python Equivelent of R BetaExpert function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Do any of the Python libraries provide an equivelent of the BetaExpert function from R? (https://rdrr.io/cran/prevalence/man/betaExpert.html)

What this does is lets you give expert opinion (ie 90% sure it's more than 0.7, most likely 0.9) and outputs the alpha/beta parameters for a Beta distribution that covers this.

scipy.stats.beta and numpy.random.beta have a various functions but nothing comparable to the R function above that I can find.

Thanks,
GD

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is given at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56371/Finding-Probability-Distribution-Parameters-from-P

```
from scipy import stats, optimize
def beta_parameters(x1, p1, x2, p2):
    "Find parameters for a beta random variable X so that P(X > x1) = p1 and P(X > x2) = p2."

    def square(x): 
        return x*x

    def objective(v):
        (a, b) = v
        temp  = square( stats.beta.cdf(x1, a, b) - p1 )
        temp += square( stats.beta.cdf(x2, a, b) - p2 )
        return temp

    # arbitrary initial guess of (3, 3) for parameters
    xopt = optimize.fmin(objective, (3, 3))
    return (xopt[0], xopt[1])
```